# Resolve workspace artifacts option in Eclipse generates error when one of the resolving projects is opened

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, artifact, hotdeploy

I have a maven project A, with 4 submodules. I have another maven project B, without any submodules. One of the 4 submodules of A, references project B.

When I do clean install on project A, I receive an error message:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) on project dca-web: Failed to copy file for artifact [be.vlaanderen.dwse:dwse-doc-tools:jar:3.2.2:compile]: /Users/Fabrizio/ontwikkeling/projecten/doc-tools/target/classes (Is a directory)

When enabling debug information: it is clear what is the issue:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) on project dca-web: Failed to copy file for artifact [be.vlaanderen.dwse:dwse-doc-tools:jar:3.2.2:compile]: /Users/Fabrizio/ontwikkeling/projecten/doc-tools/target/classes (Is a directory) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) on project dca-web: Failed to copy file for artifact [be.vlaanderen.dwse:dwse-doc-tools:jar:3.2.2:compile]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)

Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to copy file for artifact [be.vlaanderen.dwse:dwse-doc-tools:jar:3.2.2:compile]
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.packaging.ArtifactsPackagingTask.performPackaging(ArtifactsPackagingTask.java:131)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.packaging.WarProjectPackagingTask.handleArtifacts(WarProjectPackagingTask.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.packaging.WarProjectPackagingTask.performPackaging(WarProjectPackagingTask.java:109)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.AbstractWarMojo.buildWebapp(AbstractWarMojo.java:472)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.AbstractWarMojo.buildExplodedWebapp(AbstractWarMojo.java:404)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo.performPackaging(WarMojo.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo.execute(WarMojo.java:177)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/Fabrizio/ontwikkeling/projecten/doc-tools/target/classes (Is a directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.io.FileInputStreamFacade.getInputStream(FileInputStreamFacade.java:36)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.FileUtils.copyStreamToFile(FileUtils.java:1141)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1048)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.packaging.AbstractWarPackagingTask.copyFile(AbstractWarPackagingTask.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.packaging.AbstractWarPackagingTask$1.registered(AbstractWarPackagingTask.java:150)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.util.WebappStructure.registerFile(WebappStructure.java:211)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.packaging.AbstractWarPackagingTask.copyFile(AbstractWarPackagingTask.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.packaging.ArtifactsPackagingTask.performPackaging(ArtifactsPackagingTask.java:106)

But the folder target/classes is a directory! So there is a bug somewhere in one of the maven plugins I guess...

When I close project B, there is no problem. So opening the referenced project creates an issue...

I need to have project B open, because I use project A as a web application in Tomcat. When I have project B open and i change a file and save it, Eclipse does an incremental publish, and therefore Tomcat doesn't need to redeploy or restart! This saves me for each file change like 30 seconds! So it is very important to keep this project open...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. Apparently eclipse luna (or any eclipse luna based ide) is using an embedded version of maven, which in turn uses the maven-war-plugin version 2.2. After adding in my pom the version 2.6, it solved the issue!

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's because of eclipse because my project used to build a few days ago and now it's failing. Your answer was a good workaround, 1+ for you.

Comment: yeah did work for me, but how about maven-ear-plugin?
same problem, tried using no version (=2.8), 2.6 and 2.10.1.
All getting the error.

Another parallel/ similar project does not have these problems in none of the version, even not with maven-war-plugin.
Dont know what the difference is.

My workaround currently is to use install target on every single project or to cluster them into a parent projects doing this.